# Please, any suggestions with javascript (adding numeric values / prices to slider values)

Tags: javascript, html, css, constants, slider

Could anyone please help me with this?
Basically: I am working on a calculator where you can use sliders to pick the best type of option for yourself in different categories.

I have barely used javascript before, so I thought that I would ask here, as I want it to be possible to "See the pricing" later, I would like to add price values to each label.

For example, you choose "High end" (50€) under the Style of design category and "Protein2" (5€) under the Database integration category.
After you press the "See Pricing" button, a text should appear next to it saying that the pricing will be 55€.

So the question is, how do I attach various prices to these labels that you can choose from? What would be the most clean way to do it, in case someone else (not me) wants to change the prices in the code later?

[Descriptive image of what I am trying to do because I am genuinely so bad at putting things into words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPTa.png)

*What has been birthed so far:*

**HTML**:

```
<form id="divination-form">
   <h2>Project price calculator</h2>
   <h4>Use the sliders below to see what your project may end up costing!</h4>
   <div class="inputbox">
      <label for="slider1">Style of designㅤ</label>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="5" id="slider1">
      <div id="slider-label1"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="inputbox">
      <label for="slider2">Database integrationㅤ</label>
      <input type="range" min="5" max="8" id="slider2">
      <div id="slider-label2"></div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="pricing-btn">
   See Pricing
   </button>
   <div id="pricing-result" class="pricing-result-container"></div>
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
let totalPriceVisible = false;

const pricingButton = document.getElementById('pricing-btn');
pricingButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const totalPriceDiv = document.getElementById('total-price');
   if (totalPriceVisible) {
      totalPriceDiv.style.display = 'none';
      totalPriceVisible = false;
   } else {
      totalPriceDiv.style.display = 'block';
      totalPriceVisible = true;
   }
});

const labels = ['None', 'Simple', 'Moderate', 'High end', 'World class', 'Protein1', 'Protein2', 'Protein3'];
const valueLabelPairs = {
   1: 'None',
   2: 'Simple',
   3: 'Moderate',
   4: 'High end',
   5: 'World class',
   6: 'Protein1',
   7: 'Protein2',
   8: 'Protein3'
};

function setupSlider(slider, labelDiv) {
   slider.addEventListener('input', () => {
      const value = slider.value;
      const label = valueLabelPairs[value];
      labelDiv.innerHTML = label;
   });
}

setupSlider(document.getElementById('slider1'), document.getElementById('slider-label1'));
setupSlider(document.getElementById('slider2'), document.getElementById('slider-label2'));

const pricingBtn = document.getElementById('pricing-btn');
pricingBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const slider1Value = document.getElementById('slider1').value;
   const slider2Value = document.getElementById('slider2').value;
   const totalPrice = calculatePrice(slider1Value, slider2Value);
   const pricingResultContainer = document.getElementById('pricing-result');
   const pricingResult = document.createElement('div');
   pricingResult.classList.add('pricing-result');
   pricingResult.innerHTML = `Total Price: $${totalPrice}`;
   pricingResultContainer.appendChild(pricingResult);
});

const pricingButton2 = document.getElementById('pricing-btn');
let timeoutId = null;

pricingButton2.addEventListener('click', () => {
   const totalPriceDiv = document.getElementById('total-price');
   if (totalPriceDiv.style.display === 'block') {
      totalPriceDiv.style.display = 'none';
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
   } else {
      totalPriceDiv.style.display = 'block';
      timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
         totalPriceDiv.style.display = 'none';
      }, 300000); // 5 minutes
   }
});

function calculatePrice(value1, value2) {
   const prices = {
      1: 50,
      2: 100,
      3: 200,
      4: 300,
      5: 400,
      6: 500,
      7: 600,
      8: 700
   };
   const price1 = prices[value1];
   const price2 = prices[value2];
   return price1 + price2;
}
```

**This** results in you only being able to see the sum of the prices for a split second after clicking on "See Prices" button, which I am trying to find a solution to- but at the moment I am more concerned with a feeling that the code might not be as convenient or clean looking if I am planning to add a lot more sliders (which means adding more labels, prices and so on)..... So, is there a better solution to all of this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SrtackOverFlow 
I am sad to hear about your problem, so what I did understand so far is that the page refreshes or updates itself whenever you click the submit button.

That happens because the form does a submit, which means it sends the data to the backend so it refreshes the page, to fix this you need to prevent default

```
document.getElementById("divination-form").addEventListener("click", 
   function(event){
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

[For more clarification click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Another problem you might face is that it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null

This happens because the id "total-price" is not in the HTML!
which leads to failure in all of the js code, please make sure that all names, classes, and ids fit in HTML before calling them